# How to convert xacro file to urdf at ROS2?

Tags: ros2, urdf, xacro

I have a .xacro file exported from Fusion360. I want to convert it to .urdf to use at moveit2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to convert it with,

```
xacro model.xacro > model.urdf
```

However what you must do is open the xacro file and copy and past the necessary path for you description folder. Otherwise you will get an error that says can't find the path of description folder.